# HTML how do you display a global variable from Typescript?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, variables

The normal `{{variable}}` bracket method

in html doesn't display global variables.
Anyone know a solution?

Also, if an external method changes the value of this global variable, how do I update the page in the html so it shows the new value?

Answer (score 1):

What I do in my projects is a little bit hacky but works

```js
import GLOBAL_VAR

@component
class TestComponent
   GLOBAL_VAR = GLOBAL_VAR
```

So you have it in your component scope and in HTML.

Hope this will help you

Comment: indeed, you can only reference variables declared in your controller. As long as they are not primitives, they should point to the same instance than the global variables, and changes should be detected by angular.